# GNU Make: shell cat file yields contents without newlines

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash
all:
    $(eval x=$(shell cat file))
    @echo "$x"
```

File:

```
foo 
bar
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

---

How do I get the contents of the file into the make variable without losing the newlines?

Comment: You can't.  The behavior is clearly described in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with `shell`, as described in [its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).

If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make, you can use [the `file` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html) however.

Comment: Was also able to fulfill the purpose with my (old) version of make with the “$$()” call in the recipe section

Comment: Sure, if what you really want is just to have the value in the shell, and not in a make variable, then you can just use shell constructs like `$$()` and not use make functions at all.

Comment: Sometimes, you get stuck thinking a certain way.  Passing as a make variable would be useful for submakes; especially if the submake doesn’t have access to the file.  So the file command is the complete solution

Answer (score 0):

Make converts newlines from `shell` outputs to spaces  (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)):

> The shell function performs the same function that backquotes (‘`’)
>   perform in most shells: it does command expansion. This means that it
>   takes as an argument a shell command and evaluates to the output of
>   the command. The only processing make does on the result is to convert
>   each newline (or carriage-return / newline pair) to a single space. If
>   there is a trailing (carriage-return and) newline it will simply be
>   removed.

So, you cannot preserve spaces from the `$(shell)` command directly.   That being said, make *does* allow multiline variables using define -- but beware, attempting to use such variables is problematic.   Consider:

```
define x
    foo
    bar
endef

all:
     @echo "$x"
```

Make expands the $x in place, and you end up with:

```
all:
    @echo "    foo
    bar"
```

(where the newline is considered the end of the recipe line..).

Depending on what you want this for, you may be able to get around this is using a bash variable:

```
all:
    @x=$$(cat file); \
    echo $$x
```

Or potentially storing your output in a file, and referencing that when necessary.

```
all:
    eval (cat file >> output.txt)
    cat output.txt
```

(and yes, the last one is convoluted as written, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and this allows the output of your command to be persistent across recipe lines).

Answer (score 0):

If the file contents are ensured not to contain any binary data, and if you're willing to to extra processing each time you access the variable, then you could:

```
foo:=$(shell cat file | tr '\n' '\1')

all:
    @echo "$(shell echo "$(foo)" | tr '\1' '\n')"
```

Note that you cannot use nulls `\0`, and I suspect that probably means there's a buffer overflow bug in my copy of Make.